# Can this algorithm be simplified (written cleaner)?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have this algorithm, but I am not too keen on the many if-statements.

Can someone see if this function can be written in a cleaner way?

```
rand('twister',101)

n = 10;
f = A.^(0:n)./factorial(0:n);
f = f/sum(f);
n = 10000;
Xi = 2;
X = zeros(1,n);

for i =1:n,
    dXi = (-1)^round(rand);
    Yi = Xi + dXi;
    if Yi > 0 & Yi <= length(f),
        if f(Yi) >= f(Xi),
            X(i) = Yi;
            Xi = Yi;
        else
            if rand <= f(Yi)/f(Xi),
                X(i) = Yi;
                Xi = Yi;
            else
                X(i) = Xi;
            end
        end
    end
    X(i) = Xi;
end
```

Comment: What does it do?  Maybe it's already as simple as possible given the requirements.

Comment: The X(i) = Xi at the end of the loop looks like a bug.  If it's not, there's a lot of unnecessary stuff in the nested ifs where X(i) temporarily gets assigned to something else then never used.  You could simplify that to one if statement that sets Xi = Yi.

Comment: The last X(i) = Xi is intended. But I don't quite follow you, what is never used?

Comment: Higher up where you set X(i) = Yi, that value for X(i) is never read before it is changed to Xi at the end of each iteration.

Comment: Basically, Jason S, have simplified it as much as I can see possible. However, you can speed up your code by changing `dXi = (-1)^round(rand);` to `dXi = randi(2)-1;` and further more by moving it outside the for-loop and generate all random runbers at once, and then index into them, i.e. `dXi = randi(2,n,1)-1;` outside the loop and then `Yi = Xi + dXi(i);` inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Matlab syntax, but generally something like this:

```
if (cond1) then
   mainAction
else if (cond2) then
        mainAction
     else
        otherAction
```

can be simplified as:

```
if (cond1 OR cond2) then
   mainAction
else
   otherAction
```

The `OR` would have to be [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) for exact equivalence, but if `cond2` has no side-effects then it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified by noting that whenever you do `X(i) = Yi` you also do `Xi = Yi` and therefore you could just assign X(i) once at the end of the loop. This allows a lot of the other logic to simplify.

Also note that the `,` at the end of an if-clause is really only necessary in one-line if statements, e.g.

```
if x < y, do_something, else do_something_else, end
```

Anyway I get this (you could simplify further into one if statement but perhaps that's less clear. Also having more than one if statement allows breakpoints on particular sections.):

```
for i =1:n,
    dXi = (-1)^round(rand);
    Yi = Xi + dXi;
    if Yi > 0 & Yi <= length(f)
        if f(Yi) >= f(Xi) || rand <= f(Yi)/f(Xi)
            Xi = Yi;
        end
    end
    X(i) = Xi;
end
```